# Error mapping an array of objects in javascript reactjs

Tags: javascript, object, dictionary, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have an object

```
const pipe = {
diameter: 200,
C: 120,
length: 40,
accesories: [
    {name: "Bend 90°", k: 0.9, qtty: 2},
    {name: "Gate Valve", k: 0.3, qtty: 1},
    {name: "Butterfly valve", k: 0.2, qtty: 1}
  ]
}
```

I need to go through all the accessories and calculate a value with the k, example value = k * qtty.

When I do the following, it does not work

```
const perdidaslocales = (accesorio) => {accesorio.name, accesorio.k * accesorio.qtty}
const accesorieslosses = pipe.accesories.map(perdidaslocales);
```

I get in accesorieslosses [undefined, undefined, undefined]
Thank you for helping

Comment: `{accesorio.name, accesorio.k * accesorio.qtty}` makes no sense at all ... replace it with `accesorio.k * accesorio.qtty`

Comment: I need in the new array of objects, the value of the name

Comment: if `perdidaslocales` needs to return an OBJECT, wrap the return value in `()` .... and make it a valid object, i.e. ... `({name: accesorio.name, value: accesorio.k * accesorio.qtty})`

Comment: but since you're already using some ES2015+ concepts, `const perdidaslocales = ({name, k, qtty}) => ({name, value: k * qtty});`

Comment: will try the second option, because with the first I get unexpected token, expected error

Comment: @AlejandroA.E.Díaz you probably copied it wrong (before I fixed it 15 seconds after I posted the comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
const perdidaslocales = (accesorio) => {accesorio.name, accesorio.k * accesorio.qtty}
```

with

```
const perdidaslocales = (accesorio) => {
   return { 
       name: accesorio.name,
       value: accesorio.k * accesorio.qtty
   }
}
```

end result should be something like:

```
[
  {name: "Bend 90°", value: 1.8},
  {name: "Gate Valve", value: 0.3},
  {name: "Butterfly valve", value: 0.2}
]
```

Comment: Perfect. It works with this  const perdidaslocales = (accesorio) => {
   return { 
       name: accesorio.name,
       value: accesorio.k * accesorio.qtty
   }
}

Comment: Thank you @ante-jablan-adamovi%c4%87. It works. Thank you @jaromanda-x will try your solution also.

Answer (score 1):

To explain why you get undefined

```
const perdidaslocales = (accesorio) => {accesorio.name, accesorio.k * accesorio.qtty}
```

is equivalent to

```
const perdidaslocales = (accesorio) => {
    accesorio.name; 
    accesorio.k * accesorio.qtty;
}
```

see how there's no return? therefore the return value is `undefined` ...

it seems, what you're trying to do is return an object, in a simple (one line, "implied" return) arrow function you need to wrap the return value in `()` if you want to return an object or an array

The second issue is, that

```
{accesorio.name, accesorio.k * accesorio.qtty}
```

is not a valid object. Objects are key/value pairs like

```
{key1: value1, key2: value2}
```

So, in your case, you may return the name, and a value, like

```
{name: accesorio.name, value: accesorio.k * accesorio.qtty}
```

Putting this together, you get

```js
const pipe = {
    diameter: 200,
    C: 120,
    length: 40,
    accesories: [
        {name: "Bend 90°", k: 0.9, qtty: 2},
        {name: "Gate Valve", k: 0.3, qtty: 1},
        {name: "Butterfly valve", k: 0.2, qtty: 1}
    ]
}
const perdidaslocales = (accesorio) => ({name: accesorio.name, value: accesorio.k * accesorio.qtty});
const accesorieslosses = pipe.accesories.map(perdidaslocales);

console.log(accesorieslosses);
```

This can be simplified using object destructuring [See this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)

```js
const pipe = {
    diameter: 200,
    C: 120,
    length: 40,
    accesories: [
        {name: "Bend 90°", k: 0.9, qtty: 2},
        {name: "Gate Valve", k: 0.3, qtty: 1},
        {name: "Butterfly valve", k: 0.2, qtty: 1}
    ]
}
const perdidaslocales = ({name, k, qtty}) => ({name: name, value: k * qtty});
// object destructuring  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
const accesorieslosses = pipe.accesories.map(perdidaslocales);

console.log(accesorieslosses);
```

Which can be even further simplified, using [Shorthand Object property names (search for shorthand in this link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to

```js
const pipe = {
    diameter: 200,
    C: 120,
    length: 40,
    accesories: [
        {name: "Bend 90°", k: 0.9, qtty: 2},
        {name: "Gate Valve", k: 0.3, qtty: 1},
        {name: "Butterfly valve", k: 0.2, qtty: 1}
    ]
}
const perdidaslocales = ({name, k, qtty}) => ({name, value: k * qtty});
// Object shorthand property names             ^^^^^
const accesorieslosses = pipe.accesories.map(perdidaslocales);

console.log(accesorieslosses);
```

Comment: @AlejandroA.E.Díaz I find it's often better to explain the error than just provide a solution :p